# How do I change the ImageIcon for a JProgressBar?

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

Hi is this even possible?
I want to get rid of the basic blue line that shows the progress bars current progress, and replace that with a .gif file so it is more animated, rather that a static interface.

I have tried to do this, I am aware it is incorrect but any point in the right direction will hep a great deal!

`progressBar.setUI(new ImageIcon("src/images/bar.gif"));`

So I want to replace the static blue line of the progressbar, with a gif, so then I can set the progress and the gif continues "loading" e.g 20% etc.

any help would be amazing!

Comment: Was the answer below helpful?

Comment: @Assafs I have already seen that thread but thanks all the same